# trying to create a form in Visualforce page through custom controller, preview showing blank

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, inline-visualforce

***while seeing preview its showing blank on salesforce classic
also, custom controller class showing not found.***

```
<apex:page standardController="Timepagenew" >
    <apex:form>
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Enter Timesheet Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details">
            
           
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Date__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Time__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Working_Hours__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Empid__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!tsObj.Actual_Hours__c}"/>
            
            <apex:commandButton  value="Save" action="{!saveTime}"/>
            
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**custom controller class**

```
public class Timepagenew {
    public TimeSheet__c tsObj{get;set;}
    
    public Timepagenew(){
        tsObj=new TimeSheet__c();
    }
    
    public pagereference SaveTime(){
        insert tsObj;
        return new pagereference('/'+tsObj.id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

> standardController="Timepagenew"

while you need to use

> controller="Timepagenew"

For more details see:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

Comment: thanks a lot that worked